# How to listing equal rows of database table data?

Tags: php, mysql

How to Listing rows of database table data?

My database data is like this:

```
id       user_id     name        value

1           1        first      first name1

2           1        last       last name1

3           1        phone         123

4           2        first      first name2

5           2        last       last name2

6           2        phone         456
```

user_id numbers to separate users.

I want every **echo** user information to be like the following html code

```
<div class="user_1">
<span>User first name: <b>first name1</b></span>
<span>User last name: <b>last name1</b></span>
<span>User phone number: <b>123</b></span>
</div>
<div class="user_2">
<span>User first name: <b>first name2</b></span>
<span>User last name: <b>last name2</b></span>
<span>User phone number: <b>456</b></span>
</div>
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div class='user_" . $row['id_user'] . "'>";
    echo "<span>" . $row['name'] . ": <b>" . $row['value'] ."</b></span>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**But** the output is as follows:

```
<div class="user_1">
<span>first: <b>first name1</b>
</div>
<div class="user_1">
<span>last: <b>last name1</b>
</div>
<div class="user_1">
<span>phone: <b>123</b>
</div>
<div class="user_2">
<span>first: <b>first name2</b>
</div>
<div class="user_2">
<span>last: <b>last name2</b>
</div>
<div class="user_2">
<span>phone: <b>456</b>
</div>
```

Please check my **php code**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your SQL query is fine, but you should group the results by user_id first like this

```
$grouped = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (empty($grouped[$row['id_user']])) {
        $grouped[$row['id_user']] = array();
    }
    $grouped[$row['id_user']][$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Then you can output it with two foreach cycles

```
foreach ($grouped as $id => $user) {
    echo "<div class='user_$id'>\n";
    foreach ($user as $name => $value) {
        echo "<span>$name: <b>$value</b></span>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Site Error: site.com is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: I've edited the first part of code, to fix missing semicolon.

Comment: Can you write custom text instead of `$name:`?

Comment: What do you mean by custom text instead of $name? You can make some translation array that would map values in `name` column to some custom labels than use `$translationArray[$name]` instead of $name.

Comment: for example:
`foreach ($grouped as $id => $user) {
    echo "<div class='user_$id'>\n";
    foreach ($user as $name => $value) {
        echo "<span>First name: <b>$value</b></span>\n";
        echo "<span>Last name: <b>$value</b></span>\n";
        echo "<span>Phone number: <b>$value</b></span>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "<br>\n";
}`

Comment: As i said in my previous comment. You can make a translation array like this: `$translationArray = array('first' => 'First name', 'last' => 'Last name', 'phone' => 'Phone number');` Then do following while generating output: `echo "<span>{$translationArray[$name]}: <b>$value</b></span>\n";`

Comment: Is it possible to hide the phone number?
In fact, do not echo the phone.

Comment: Add `WHERE name != 'phone'` into your SQL query.